# Java. Get value from Spreadsheet object (list of lists)

Tags: java, json, google-sheets

I'm getting a spreadsheet object with CellData

```
        var request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId);
        request.set("fields", "sheets/data/rowData/values/note");
        request.setRanges(ranges);
        var spreadsheet = request.execute();
        var resultString = spreadsheet.toString();
```

The object returned looks like this:

[image: Debug console]

I need to get just a value of **note** from this.

toString() method returns

```
{"sheets":[{"data":[{"rowData":[{"values":[{"note":"test note"}]}]}]}]}
```

I obviously can get value by just searching in that string, but what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response to this API call is the [Spreadsheet resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) which, in the Java library, is managed by the [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/Spreadsheet.html).

The Spreadsheet class has a [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/Spreadsheet.html#getSheets--) method, which returns a list of [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/Sheet.html). Since you only have one sheet, get the first element in the spreadsheet (the first sheet), and use the corresponding method to get the sheet's [GridData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/GridData.html).

Repeat the same process for [RowData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/RowData.html) and [CellData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/CellData.html) until you reach the `note` via [getNote()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/CellData.html#getNote--):

#### Code example:

```
Spreadsheet spreadsheet = request.execute();
Sheet sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets().get(0);
GridData data = sheet.getData().get(0);
RowData rowData = data.getRowData().get(0);
CellData cellData = rowData.getValues().get(0);
String note = cellData.getNote();
```

#### Notes:

- Based on the information you provided, I assumed you only have one element in each of the lists (that is, you only want to retrieve a single cell in a single sheet). If that's not the case, you should loop through the corresponding list instead of accessing its first element.
- Don't forget to import the modules for all these classes.